# How do I create flow arrows on top of a one line equation like this?

Tags: arrows

I want to replicate the arrows like this:

[image]

I have no expertise in `tikz`, so I couldn't really think of a solution. Any idea how I can achieve this?

A MWE for the equation is this:

```
\begin{equation}
I_{hkl} \equiv I_{\bar{h} \bar{k} \bar{\ell}} \equiv I_{\bar{h} k \ell} \equiv I_{h \bar{k} \bar{\ell}} \equiv I_{h \bar{k} \ell} \equiv I_{\bar{h} k \bar{\ell}} \equiv I_{h k \bar{\ell}} \equiv I_{\bar{h} \bar{k} \ell}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Use `tikzmark` library of `tikz` package is way to go! Please provide a MWE with your equation.

Comment: @Zarko Added MWE.

Comment: Well, this only code fragment, not an MWE :-), but thank you for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho,  % -|- and |-| path operations
                quotes,
                tikzmark,
                }
\tikzset{
 is/.style = {inner ysep=2pt},
lbl/.style = {anchor=#1, inner sep=1pt, align=center, 
              font=\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,}
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
I_{\tikzmarknode[is]{A}{h}kl} 
    \equiv I_{\tikzmarknode[is]{B}{\bar{h}} \bar{k} \bar{\ell}} 
    \equiv I_{\tikzmarknode[is]{C}{\bar{h}} \tikzmarknode[is]{D}{k} \ell}
    \equiv I_{h \tikzmarknode[is]{E}{\bar{k}} \bar{\ell}}
    \equiv I_{h \bar{k} \ell} 
    \equiv I_{\bar{h} k \bar{\ell}} 
    \equiv I_{h k \bar{\ell}} 
    \equiv I_{\bar{h} \bar{k} \ell}
\end{equation}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[->]           ([xshift=+1pt] A) |-|[distance=5mm] (B.south) node[lbl=center, pos=0.5] {text\\text};
\draw[ ->, teal]    ([xshift=-1pt] A) |-|[distance=9mm] (C.south) node[lbl=south, pos=0.6] {text};
\draw[<->, teal]    (D.south) to[bend right=45, "text" lbl=north] (E.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
More complete suggestion. Now are drawn all arrows and are care for space for image with arrows. Due to pure quality of your images the positions of node may be wrong. Also I left to you replacing the words "text" with real content to you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho,  % -|- and |-| path operations
                quotes,
                tikzmark,
                }
\tikzset{
 is/.style = {inner ysep=2pt},
lbl/.style = {anchor=#1, inner sep=1pt, align=center,
              font=\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont},
lbl/.default=south
        }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
\begin{equation}
\tikzmarknode[is]{a}{I}_{\tikzmarknode[is]{b}{h}kl}
    \equiv I_{\tikzmarknode[is]{c}{\bar{h}} \bar{k} \bar{\ell}}
    \equiv I_{\tikzmarknode[is]{d}{\bar{h}} \tikzmarknode[is]{e}{k} \ell}
    \equiv I_{h \tikzmarknode[is]{f}{\bar{k}} \bar{\ell}}
    \equiv \tikzmarknode[is]{g}{I}_{h \bar{k} \tikzmarknode[is]{h}{\ell}}
    \equiv I_{\bar{h} k \tikzmarknode[is]{i}{\bar{\ell}}}
    \equiv \tikzmarknode[is]{j}{I}_{h k \tikzmarknode[is]{k}{\bar{\ell}}}
    \equiv I_{\bar{h}\bar{k} \tikzmarknode[is]{l}{\ell}}
\end{equation}
    \begin{center}  % <--- for space of image
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[ ->]          ([xshift=+1pt] b) |-|[distance=5mm]  (c.south) node[lbl, pos=0.5] {FL};
\draw[ ->, teal]    ([xshift=-1pt] b) |-|[distance=7mm]  (d.south) node[lbl, pos=0.6] {text};
\draw[ ->, purple]  ([xshift=+1pt] a) |-|[distance=10mm] (g.south) node[lbl, pos=0.6] {text};
\draw[ ->, purple]  ([xshift=-1pt] a) |-|[distance=12mm] (j.south) node[lbl, pos=0.7] {text};
%
\draw[<->, blue]    (e.south) to[bend right=45, "FL" lbl=north] (f.south);
\draw[<->, blue]    (h.south) to[bend right=45, "FL" lbl=north] (i.south);
\draw[<->, blue]    (k.south) to[bend right=45, "FL" lbl=north] (l.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{3ex}        % <--- additional space for image
    \end{center}
where FL means Freadel's law?

\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:**  For final look of code you need to compile MWE at least three times.

Comment: That is helpful. Is there any way to force the arrows to go below or above the equation? When I am adding more arrows, some arrows go above the equation, which is fine. But the moment I add a positive `yshift`, the arrow comes down, irrespective of the `distance` parameter,

Comment: @WrichikBasu, I propose a solution. In it I didn't use any `yshift`. Why and where you use it? In your sketch all arrows are below equation.. Frankly said, sketch is not accurate, so it can be easy to miss a variables, which should be connected by arrows.  All arrows should be drawn on the same way. I add one more bended  arrow, that you can see how to handle it (it require library `quotes`), You can select own `tikzmark` nodes names, which will be more meaning ful to you. to Provide a better sketch!

Comment: @WrichikBasu, you may consider to ask new question, where you show, how you use my code and where you stuck.

Comment: I tried the `yshift` because some aoorws were going above instead of below, and they were literally going inside the `I_{hkl}` because `h` was marked as the node. Anyway, with the full example, it's working fine now. Thanks for the help.